# Assign dynamic html tag content by using angular function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I need to assign a dynamic html tag content to links.
Right now I have two links, one of which disabled. But I need to dynamically specify if it is disabled or not by calling function in my Angular 1 code.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/blue.css" title="blue" disabled/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/red.css" title="red" />
```

Kindly appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the directive `ng-disabled`. You can learn more about this directive on the [official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) of AngularJS.

**Example of implementation for your case:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/blue.css" title="blue" ng-disabled="expression" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/red.css" title="red" ng-disabled="expression" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ng-disabled`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/blue.css" title="blue"
      ng-disabled="{condition}" />
```